# A question about the kanji 畀?

Tags: kanji

When I searched for this kanji in japanese dictionaries i didn't found many results just found it in the popular sites like [wiktionary page](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%95%80#)  and [jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/%E7%95%80)  it means "to give" and there is no example words containing it and also the same thing with the kanjis are contianing it like 箅, 淠 and 痹 all of them have resulst but haven't word examples

But the strange thing is there is only one kanji contain it 鼻 (nose) and it has example words in all dictionaries and it's also a radical and a common kanji so why is this kanji especially known in the dictionaries among all of these kanjis which contain 畀?

And the funny is also the kanjis which contain 鼻 haven't example words in the dictionaries like this 嚊.

So the question is why this kanji 畀 and its related kanjis haven't example words? Are they not common or deleted or something like that ?
And why espically 鼻 (nose) among the kanjis related to 畀 has examples and is very common ?
I believe that there is someone have the answer.

Comment: Could you please make it more clear what exactly your question is?

Comment: I edited the comment

Comment: https://kanji.jitenon.jp/kanjiu/10303.html   https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%95%80

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're trying to break down *kanji* into constituent components and learn those components. I agree that this is the most logical way to learn *kanji*.

However, as you've also noticed, you cannot find many definitions of one of the breakdown components of「鼻」.

> 「鼻{び}」is composed of semantic「自」and phonetic「畀{ひ}」, although please note that in Japanese, the bottom part of「鼻」is written as「廾」rather than its appearance in Chinese as「丌」.
>
> For reference,「自」was originally a picture of a *nose*.
>
> ## <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image]
> [甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)392
> [合集33314](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=33314&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image]
> 沈子它簋蓋
> [集成4330](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=4330&jgwfl=)</kbd>
> <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
> [image]
> [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
> 　<kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image]</kbd>
>
> The shape of the nostrils is no longer explicit in the third form above, leading to the modern form.

It pays to remember again that *kanji* were originally created for the Chinese language(s). The overwhelmingly common way of writing *nose* in Chinese is「{{kr:鼻}}」, and this is the character that Japanese adopted to also write *nose*. However, this does not automatically mean that Japanese would adopt the components of「鼻」as common characters.

Chinese characters number in the order of 10,000~100,000, so don't expect Japanese to adopt all those characters. Japanese only adopts what is needed from Chinese characters to make the characters work in the Japanese language!

---

Explicitly,

> 畀 箅 淠 痹 嚊 etc.

cannot be found in common dictionaries with example sentences because they are simply not part of the *kanji* that Japanese ordinarily uses.

Comment: @user32763 you might want to read up on e.g. [*Jōyō kanji*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji) for what constitutes a common character list, although *Jōyō kanji* really only constitutes the bare minimum of functioning literacy in Japanese.